# Why does my JOptionPane repeatedly prompt for Major Sheet status from my code below

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm having an infinite while loop issue, no matter what I type in even if it is "Filed" or "Incomplete" the loop keeps re prompting and I can't figure out why.

```
strMajorSheet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is the advisee's major sheet status? (Filed/Incomplete)",
                "Advisee's Major Sheet",3);

if(strMajorSheet == "Filed" || strMajorSheet == "Incomplete")
                    {

                        switch(strMajorSheet)
                        {
                            case "Filed":
                                blnMajorSheet = true;
                            case "Incomplete":
                                blnMajorSheet = false;


                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while(strMajorSheet != "Filed" && strMajorSheet != "Incomplete")
                        {
                            strMajorSheet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is the advisee's major sheet status? (Filed/Incomplete)",
                                "Advisee's Major Sheet",3);


                        }
```

Comment: Why the `if` statement AND `case` statement?  You could do the whole thing with the `case` statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please don't compare String using `==`

change it to

```
if(strMajorSheet.equals("Filed") || strMajorSheet.equals("Incomplete"))
......

while(!strMajorSheet.equals("Filed") && !strMajorSheet.equals("Incomplete"))
......
```

Comment: Oh my goodness I completely goofed. I'm still a beginner when it comes to programming, much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison Java must be done using `equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `String` comparison is not done using `==`, which compares the object references, which are unlikely to be `true` very often.  Instead, you need to use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare the contents of the two `String`s.

Having said that, I don't know why you're bothering with the `if` statement as the entire logic can be achieved using just the `switch` statement, for example...

```
boolean gotInput = true;

do {
    String strMajorSheet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the advisee's major sheet status? (Filed/Incomplete)",
                    "Advisee's Major Sheet", 3);

    gotInput = true;
    switch (strMajorSheet) {
        case "Filed":
            blnMajorSheet = true;
            break;
        case "Incomplete":
            blnMajorSheet = false;
            break;
        default:
            gotInput = false;
    }
} while (!gotInput);
```

Now, beware, that `switch (String)` is the same as using `String#equals`, that is, it's case sensitive comparison.